# How can I use vuetify 1.5?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I got a old vue project with vuetify 1.5.14 and they want me to add something. The project is not working local and I don't want to upload my changes everytime. My plan was it to create a new project with vuetify 1.5 to test what I need to implement. My problem now is, that it isn't possible to create a new vue project with vuetify 1. So my question is: Is there a way to create a project with vuetify 1.5? I would be so thankful if someone can help me.

I tried to downgrade a project from vuetify 2 to vuetify 1.5 with npm install vuetify@1.5.14 --save and changed the version-number in package.json -> didn't work. Then I deleted the node_modules and package-log and npm install again -> didn't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several sandboxes around with Vuetify 1.x, for example [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/loll9pv5l?file=/package.json). Have a look at the [search results](https://codesandbox.io/search?query=vuetify+1.) maybe one of them works for you?

Though it does not seem hard to create a project with Vuetify 1.5:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      vuetifyVersion: Vuetify.version
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn>Hello Vuetify {{ vuetifyVersion }}</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.js "></script>
<link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
```

Maybe the sandbox can help how to set it up in a project with a builder.